# How to get ciphertext_len from ciphertext to use in openssl EVP_ in c program

Tags: c, linux, openssl

In order to find `ciphertext_len` from ciphertext to use in openssl EVP_ in  C program I have created a ciphertext using OpenSSL in bash to give base64 output:

```
echo -n "Hello"|openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -nosalt -K 
000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F -iv 
000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F|base64 -w0
```

A program to decrypt in C from the example I found it works for the above bash command but if I give:

```
./evp_decrypt 0t3Z18pJqxIbbCFlnqDBIjMSFFvaOEoA7HFuRjQeExA0B1zCJoBhIzV5Qj3JU44qLcI+qbyLG/b2WJE2weKDynX6WJ/9OlujH6tTlITsbw4/hVpxZJnFFF6PfD5Hqyjct6YcLlmhtXYjZab9MsaPO+m/RJH+koe+FUdzxNJpjtWEgijaWQkpDLszsXTKgM+XXZloi6WQicItDRj02iQvXEAmGxejBbekWq0y1LX+SpQ=
```

```c
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INBUFSIZE 512
#define OUTBUFSIZE (1024*1024)


char *base64encode (const void *b64_encode_this, int encode_this_many_bytes){
    BIO *b64_bio, *mem_bio;      //Declares two OpenSSL BIOs: a base64 filter and a memory BIO.
    BUF_MEM *mem_bio_mem_ptr;    //Pointer to a "memory BIO" structure holding our base64 data.
    b64_bio = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());                      //Initialize our base64 filter BIO.
    mem_bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());                           //Initialize our memory sink BIO.
    BIO_push(b64_bio, mem_bio);            //Link the BIOs by creating a filter-sink BIO chain.
    BIO_set_flags(b64_bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);  //No newlines every 64 characters or less.
    BIO_write(b64_bio, b64_encode_this, encode_this_many_bytes); //Records base64 encoded data.
    BIO_flush(b64_bio);   //Flush data.  Necessary for b64 encoding, because of pad characters.
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(mem_bio, &mem_bio_mem_ptr);  //Store address of mem_bio's memory structure.
    BIO_set_close(mem_bio, BIO_NOCLOSE);   //Permit access to mem_ptr after BIOs are destroyed.
    BIO_free_all(b64_bio);  //Destroys all BIOs in chain, starting with b64 (i.e. the 1st one).
    BUF_MEM_grow(mem_bio_mem_ptr, (*mem_bio_mem_ptr).length + 1);   //Makes space for end null.
    (*mem_bio_mem_ptr).data[(*mem_bio_mem_ptr).length] = '\0';  //Adds null-terminator to tail.
    return (*mem_bio_mem_ptr).data; //Returns base-64 encoded data. (See: "buf_mem_st" struct).
}

char *base64decode (const void *b64_decode_this, int decode_this_many_bytes){
    BIO *b64_bio, *mem_bio;      //Declares two OpenSSL BIOs: a base64 filter and a memory BIO.
    char *base64_decoded = calloc( (decode_this_many_bytes*3)/4+1, sizeof(char) ); //+1 = null.
    b64_bio = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());                      //Initialize our base64 filter BIO.
    mem_bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());                         //Initialize our memory source BIO.
    BIO_write(mem_bio, b64_decode_this, decode_this_many_bytes); //Base64 data saved in source.
    BIO_push(b64_bio, mem_bio);          //Link the BIOs by creating a filter-source BIO chain.
    BIO_set_flags(b64_bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);          //Don't require trailing newlines.
    int decoded_byte_index = 0;   //Index where the next base64_decoded byte should be written.
    while ( 0 < BIO_read(b64_bio, base64_decoded+decoded_byte_index, 1) ){ //Read byte-by-byte.
        decoded_byte_index++; //Increment the index until read of BIO decoded data is complete.
    } //Once we're done reading decoded data, BIO_read returns -1 even though there's no error.
    BIO_free_all(b64_bio);  //Destroys all BIOs in chain, starting with b64 (i.e. the 1st one).
    return base64_decoded;        //Returns base-64 decoded data with trailing null terminator.
}




void prtErrAndExit(int eVal, char *msg);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int outBytes, inBytes, tmpOutBytes, bytesInBuf, i;
  int cipherBlockSize, cipherKeyLength, cipherIvLength;
  unsigned char key[] = { /* Need all 32 bytes... */
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 
    0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F
  };
  unsigned char iv[] = { /* Only need 16 bytes... */
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 
    0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F
  };
  unsigned char buf2crypt[INBUFSIZE];
  unsigned char outBuf[OUTBUFSIZE];
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
  EVP_DecryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

  cipherBlockSize = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(&ctx); 
  cipherKeyLength = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(&ctx);
  cipherIvLength  = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(&ctx);

  fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt): Enc Algo:   %s\n", OBJ_nid2ln(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_nid(&ctx)));
  fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt): Key:        ");
  for(i=0; i<cipherKeyLength; i++)
    fprintf(stderr, "%02X", (int)(key[i]));
  fprintf(stderr, "\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt): IV:         ");
  for(i=0; i<cipherIvLength; i++)
    fprintf(stderr, "%02X", (int)(iv[i]));
  fprintf(stderr, "\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt): block size: %d\n", cipherBlockSize);
  fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt): key length: %d\n", cipherKeyLength);
  fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt): IV length:  %d\n", cipherIvLength);

  if((cipherKeyLength > 32) || (cipherIvLength  > 16))
    prtErrAndExit(1, "ERROR: Hardwired key or iv was too short!!\n"); 

  //fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt): READING DATA");
  inBytes = outBytes = 0;
    char *input_base64encoded = argv[1];
    int bytes_to_decode = strlen(input_base64encoded)+1; //Number of bytes in string to base64 decode.
     //unsigned char buf2crypt[INBUFSIZE];
    char *base64_decoded_encrypted = base64decode(input_base64encoded, bytes_to_decode);   //Base-64 decoding.

    bytesInBuf =  strlen(base64_decoded_encrypted); // HOW TO GET LENGTH OF ciphertext
    BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)base64_decoded_encrypted, bytesInBuf);

    if((OUTBUFSIZE - ((bytesInBuf + cipherBlockSize - 1) + outBytes)) <= 0)
      prtErrAndExit(1, "ERROR: Buffer was not big enough to hold decrypted data!!\n");
      //printf ("%d and %d, %d, %s, %d \n", outBuf, outBytes, tmpOutBytes, base64_decoded_encrypted, bytesInBuf);
       printf ("tmpOutBytes before is %d\n", tmpOutBytes);



    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, outBuf + outBytes, &tmpOutBytes, base64_decoded_encrypted, bytesInBuf))
      prtErrAndExit(1, "ERROR: EVP_DecryptUpdate didn't work...\n");
     printf ("tmpOutBytes before is %d\n", tmpOutBytes);
    outBytes += tmpOutBytes;
    inBytes += bytesInBuf;
;

  if((OUTBUFSIZE - (cipherBlockSize + outBytes)) <= 0)
    prtErrAndExit(1, "ERROR: Buffer was not big enough to hold decrypted data!!\n");
  if(!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&ctx, outBuf+outBytes, &tmpOutBytes))
    prtErrAndExit(1, "ERROR: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex didn't work...\n");
  outBytes += tmpOutBytes;

  fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt): Bytes in:   %d\n", inBytes);
  fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt): Bytes out:  %d\n", outBytes);

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

  //fwrite(outBuf, 1, outBytes, stdout);
  //outBuf has length of array ie with empty space filled 
  printf("The decrypted is %s\n", outBuf);

  char *rtrim(char *str, const char *seps)
{
    int i;
    if (seps == NULL) {
        seps = "\t\n\v\f\r ";
    }
    i = strlen(str) - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && strchr(seps, str[i]) != NULL) {
        str[i] = '\0';
        i--;
    }
    return str;
}

    char *decrypted_key =  rtrim(outBuf, NULL) ;
   printf("The trimmed decrypted is %s\n", decrypted_key);
  return 0;
} /* end func main */

/* Save some vertical space with this simple error handling function.. */
void prtErrAndExit(int eVal, char *msg) {
  if(msg != NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt_error): %s\n\n", msg);
    fprintf(stderr, "INFO(evp_decrypt_error_message): \n\n");

  exit(eVal);
} /* end func prtErrAndExit */
```

I know something wrong in getting length of the ciphertext - how can I fix it?

Comment: See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. You might also want to look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I already gone throuth the documentation i would like to get clarified on how to get  ciphertext_len from the ciphertext (a binary data). Those examples get the ciphertext_len from the encrypt function. But in my case i have to do decrypt only.

Answer (score 0):

Ciphertext is arbitrary bits and you can't determine its length by looking at it, you must know already what its length is. In particular ciphertext can contain a null byte, which terminates a C string, and this will cause `strlen` to return too small a value. However, you actually have a base64 string *passed from the commandline* which *is* a null-terminated C string, so `strlen()` gives the correct length, and decoding that base64 gives a known amount of data -- the final value of `decoded_byte_index` in your decode function. Since you also want to pass back the (alloc'ed) pointer you need to handle *two* values; to do this in C you can (1) use a pointer argument/parameter that the function stores through; (2) set a shared global that is read by the caller, but shared globals are widely considered very bad style; or (3) create a suitable `struct` type and use that.

But you don't need all that hassle with BIOs. Your entire decode function could be replaced by one call to `EVP_DecodeBlock` which conveniently returns the number of bytes in the decoded result as an `int`, using a supplied buffer instead of alloc'ing. (And your encode function could be replaced by `EVP_EncodeBlock`, except it isn't used or needed at all.)

The decrypted value similarly is not null-terminated and cannot be safely treated as a C string: `printf("The decrypted is %s\n", outBuf)` may run past the end of the valid data and print garbage or even crash, and `rtrim` using `strlen(str)` may access past the end of your actual buffer and clobber other data. Instead use the length you computed by adding up the 'outl' arguments, i.e. the final value of `outBytes`. For the printf you can use `printf ("%.*s\n", outBytes, outBuf)` to truncate at the specified length instead of searching for the absent null byte.

Finally, when an OpenSSL function returns an error indication, instead of simply saying 'didn't work' it is almost always good to at least print the value of `ERR_get_error()` (preferably in hex), or better the result of calling `ERR_get_error_string()` on that number, or best to call `ERR_print_errors[_fp|cb]` to print the number *and* string *and* some other data that may help figure out the problem. All of these are described on their respective man pages.

You might also want to consider that nested functions (your `rtrim` within `main`) are a GCC extension not in standard C and not implemented by most other compilers. And in your case not needed.

Comment: thanks for suggesting EVP_DecodeBlock, i could not find examples of this decode_block as iam new can some one please modify it to working. thanks again dave thompson